# Exponential Moving Average

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

What is the formula of Exponential Moving Average (EMA) in Google sheet ?

How it can be used to calculate Share market stock EMA of different period. Eg 5, 21, 50 Days.

Can anyone share Demo sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) this function:

```
/**
 * Calculates the Exponential Moving Average of the range.
 *
 * @param {range} range The range of cells to calculate.
 * @param {number} n The number of trailing samples to give higer weight to, e.g. 30.
 * @return The EMA of the range.
 * @customfunction
 */
function EMA(range, n) {
  if (!range.reduce) return range;
  n = Math.min(n, range.length);
  var m = 2 / (n + 1);

  return range.reduce(function(acc, x, index, array) {
    return x != "" ? (x * m + acc * (1 - m)) : acc;
  }, 0);
}
```

[source](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8141206)